# Public transport options between Paris and EuroDisney

Tags: public-transport, france, paris, disney

We're based in the UK, trying to arrange a family holiday for next year where everyone can enjoy themselves. So, a few days at Eurodisney and a few days in the city of Paris.

We don't want to stay on site at the theme park - too expensive, and would mean relocating to the city. We also don't really want a hotel - we'd rather have a self-catering cottage of some kind.

We also don't want to take the car. So we'll be reliant on public transport.

My knowledge of the local geography is zero, and I can't seem to find much out with google - search results focus on "official" accommodation or mass-booking sites, with very little helpful information.

So here's the question: what towns or villages should I be looking at to find self-catering accommodation where it is easy to get on a train or bus into both the city of Paris and Eurodisney? Bonus points if you can tell me the travel times. Big bonus points if you can find me somewhere to stay :)

Comment: you can stay anywhere in Paris and take the subway, you can also stay in Air BnB for self-catered apartments.  Where exactly you want to stay is personal preference

Comment: see this website for a guide on taking the local trains to Disneyland http://parisbytrain.com/rer-train-paris-to-euro-disney/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Réseau Express Régional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9seau_Express_R%C3%A9gional) (RER) commuter express rail network (Line A) stops within walking distance of the park. Board the RER in Paris at Charles-de-Gaulle–Étoile, Châtelet–Les Halles, Nation or any other stop. Get off at Line A’s last stop, Marne-la-Vallée–Chessy, 45 minutes from central Paris. Make sure you take the right branch (Eurodisney is indicated on most signs). The round-trip fare is 12€. Trains run daily, every 10 to 20 minutes from 5:30am to midnight.

On Google Maps, RER stations appear as little white circles with the letters RER inside it. On French maps, line A is the red one.

So you could stay at any of the communities near an RER station. Take for example Noisy-le-Grand, which favours Eurodisney in terms of commute time and has nice accommodation offerings.  Or Vincennes, which is closer to the centre of Paris and has more of a urban ambience.  Or you could stay right in the heart of Paris at the Étoile.  We can't recommend an accommodation by name and which locale you select along the RER line will ultimately be a matter of personal preference.

However, I do not think looking for self-catering cottages (of the sort you would find around Blackpool or Torquay) will be fruitful unless you look much further to the east, for example Château-Thierry, but the public transport connections to Eurodisney won't be good.  You can also check the [Paris - Airbnb site](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Paris?zoom=12&search_by_map=true&sw_lat=48.755204100947374&sw_lng=2.6494903329195267&ne_lat=48.91443962508579&ne_lng=2.8369445565523392&ss_id=y4kk2lji) to see what accommodation is available from local hosts.

The RER is in the greater Paris transportation scheme and if you go between Paris and Eurodisney you would probably be most interested in the Paris Visite tickets. Marne-la-Vallée/Eurodisney is in zone 5.

> The Paris Visite is an all-day ticket with four periods of validity:
>   one two, three or five consecutive days. It allows unlimited travel
>   within the chosen zones (1–3 or 1–5) on all modes of transport –
>   except the Jetbus network, the Filéo at Charles de Gaulle Airport,
>   tourist buses, and Air France services – and allows travel to Charles
>   de Gaulle and Orly airports.[14]

Source:  [Public transport fares in the Île-de-France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_transport_fares_in_the_%C3%8Ele-de-France#Paris_Visite)

See also: [Frommer's France 2011](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470614382)

Comment: Note that for many tourists the Paris Visite pass actually costs more than individual tickets. But with trips to Marne-la-Vallée, there's a good chance that it's worth it.

Comment: @Gilles, got it, and many thanks for the valuable edit. Grateful for that!